# How to get unicode from font/glyph or unicode range from font?

Tags: unicode, fonts, icons, glyph

I use [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) created an icon font file from svg, now i am writing an app(objective c mac os) to read this icon file.

the problem is how to get unicode range and icon unicode?

Input: an icon font file(NSFont  CTFont)

Output: i want get the unicode for every icon pic in this icon file

Comment: Here's an interesting blow-by-blow of reading a TTF file in Javascript, don't know if it will help. http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=143

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks, but it's nothing talking about unicode.